# Minimal Distance Hamiltonian Path Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, traveling-salesman

I know this is a fairly frequent question (tsp in general), but I've been stumped by it for awhile now. I'm looking to find the minimal distance hamiltonian path given a set of x,y coordinates. The start and end point are completely arbitrary but it must NOT cycle, so standard tsp is out (although supposedly adding a dummy point at 0 distance to all other nodes and then removing it later works, i have no idea how I'd do that).

There are plenty of links to math papers and the like discussing algorithms to solve similar problems, but I'd much rather work with code than complex equations and i'd really rather not reinvent the wheel.

Surely there is a fairly straightforward implementation in a major language java,c#,c++,ruby,javascript,php,etc that can solve a ~20 node version of my problem.

**Edit:** I'm also looking for as accurate as possible, obviously it can't be completely accurate as 20! is a lot of permutations, but equal to or better than what a human could do in a couple minutes would be perfect.

**Edit2:** Also to clarify, I'm working with standard 2d coordinates on an unweighted graph. The distance A->B == B->A

**Edit3:**  To eliminate confusion, here's a visual example with just a few points to show how tsp can be suboptimal (this case is an easy fix but with more nodes it can be more extreme).

TSP Minus Longest Segment (red line)

[image: TSP Minus Longest Segment (red line)]

Desired Output

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: I think the idea with the dummy point at zero distance from everything else is that the TSP answer will use two links of length zero, one to that dummy point and one from that dummy point. Therefore the cost of the TSP in the modified problem is exactly the cost of your Hamiltonian path, and minimising this produces the cost of the minimum Hamiltonian path, which you can recover by deleting the dummy node and the links to and from it.

Comment: I've modified a free library to do exactly this: www.chihoang.de/index.php?id=1373. It uses an ant colony optimization algorithm. I check it with a double minimum spanning tree. I'm not too sure if my method is terrible scientific but you are welcome to take a look?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the bitonic euclidean traveling-salesman problem. Is a simplified version of the tsp solvable through dynamic programming in `O(n^2)`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_tour

Comment: Looks like that creates a closed circuit though :/. In certain configurations simply removing the longest segment in a closed circuit doesn't produce a good solution to my problem.

Comment: if you solve the tsp and then you remove the longest semgment you must have the better path between them. if this was false, then we can find another circuit that pass through that points add the segment you removed and you get a shortest solution for the tsp

Comment: Take a look at the images, unless I'm missing something I'm pretty sure the tsp approach won't work. If you think it'll still work after seeing the images I'll try figuring out what you mean.

Comment: ok maybe you're right...but adding a dummy node will do for sure both for the bitonic tour both for the tsp